# I am getting an error on my wordpress page and don't know whats causing it

Tags: wordpress, web, helper

I am getting this Error and don't have a clue what I should do to fix it:

```
Warning: Creating default object from empty value in /www/wp-content/miwi/framework/application/module/helper.php on line 91
```

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually caused by compatibility issues in PHP, normally plugins or your host has upgraded PHP. As long as your site continues working, it's just an error message and you shouldn't care, so in your wp-config file you need to add one of the following, depending on your server:

```
@ini_set( 'log_errors', 'Off' );
@ini_set( 'display_errors', 'On' );
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', false );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
```

for more information, see [Configure Error Logging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Configure_Error_Logging)

Comment: Thank you!
The last line fixed it!